React router 6.22.3 is not showing only in production mode, why?
This question is already asked but slightly differently, i.e. for me the router is not rendered only when using the built project, otherwise in dev mode everything is fine. Why it happens so and how should I fix it?
dev routes that work:

"http://localhost:5173/"
"http://localhost:5173/#/about"

production routes (don't work):

"https://my-domain/audio-ui/"
"https://my-domain/audio-ui/#/about"

I build with tsc && vite build --base=/audio-ui/ because I need the /audio-ui subpath. I have another project where I use the same build approach and it works fine but I'm not using React-Router-DOM there.
The entire (simple) project is at https://github.com/adrhc/audio-ui/tree/RouterProvider_only.
main.tsx content:
// import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard.tsx';
import '@fontsource/roboto/300.css';
import '@fontsource/roboto/400.css';
import '@fontsource/roboto/500.css';
import '@fontsource/roboto/700.css';
// import { CssBaseline, ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material';
import { RouterProvider, createHashRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Volume from './Volume.tsx';
import About from './About.tsx';
import ErrorPage from './ErrorPage.tsx';
import Root from './Root.tsx';

const router = createHashRouter(
  [
    {
      path: '/',
      element: <Root />,
      errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
      children: [
        {
          path: '',
          element: <Dashboard />,
        },
        {
          path: 'volume',
          element: <Volume />,
        },
        {
          path: 'about',
          element: <About />,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
  { basename: import.meta.env.BASE_URL }
);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <RouterProvider router={router} />
);


Unlike the BrowserRouter the HashRouters don't really need the basename prop since they work from "/" from whatever "..../#/" static URL they are served from.
In other words, all page requests to the server are "https://my-domain/audio-ui/" and everything after the hash is ignored by the server and handled client-side by the HashRouter.
If import.meta.env.BASE_URL is the value "/audio-ui/" then you are actually telling React-Router and the HashRouter to use URLs like:

"https://my-domain/audio-ui/#/audio-ui/"
"https://my-domain/audio-ui/#/audio-ui/about"

You are saying that "https://my-domain/audio-ui/#/audio-ui/" is the root route and that all routes and links work relative to this location.
If you are hosting and serving the React app from "https://my-domain/audio-ui" then remove the basename prop from the HashRouter so it uses "/" as the root path to route/navigate/link from. All routes/links will work from "https://my-domain/audio-ui/#/" now.
const router = createHashRouter(
  [
    {
      path: '/',
      element: <Root />,
      errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
      children: [
        {
          path: '',
          element: <Dashboard />,
        },
        {
          path: 'volume',
          element: <Volume />,
        },
        {
          path: 'about',
          element: <About />,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
);

Or keep the basename prop ({ basename: import.meta.env.BASE_URL }) and use tsc && vite build --base=/ to build the app.
